# Compiling a C++ code in in shinyapp.io

Tags: c++, r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a C++ code (hello world code that prints "hello world!" in a text file).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("Hello_World.txt");
myfile << "Hello World! This is a test.\n";
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I want to see if it's possible to compile my C++ code on shinyapp.io and then execute the compiled file on the server and get the "Hello_World.txt" file? If not, how should I compile my code on my local machine so it can be executed in shinyapp.io once I transfer the compiled code on server?

I am more concerned about the approach (compiling a Fortran or C++ code on local machine and running on shinyapp.io). My goal is to extend the approach for more complex code in future.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you using Rcpp? Can you put your code in a package?

Comment: Thank you MrFlick for the response. No, I have not used Rcpp. In fact my actual code is a fortran code, but I first just wanted to start with a simple code as above to see the approach works or not. How can I put my code in a package? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ is a good start for package creation.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile cpp-files without problems, see your code adopted & deployed for shinyapp.io:

app.R:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(shiny)

Rcpp::sourceCpp("test_rcpp.cpp")


shiny::shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(hello()),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("content of Hello_world.txt"),
      mainPanel(readChar("Hello_World.txt", file.info("Hello_World.txt")$size))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

test_rcpp.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). Learn
// more about Rcpp at:
//
//   http://www.rcpp.org/
//   http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html
//   http://gallery.rcpp.org/
//

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector hello() {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("Hello_World.txt");
  myfile << "Hello World! This is a test.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return "Hello, World is saved";
;
}


// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
*/
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An update:

I was finally able to execute the compiled code on shinyapp.io. There was a mistake about the file permission, and I used to get the `permission denied` error on shinyapp.io log. Until I found out that I need to set the permission for the compiled code on the server.R (with `system()` command) during the execution on shinyapp.io, not on my local machine. Thank you all for your comments.